# I'm wondering if there is some general text block used to try to "break" inputs such as textfields

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm in the middle of creating a forum plugin for PHPDevShell and I've gotten to the point where I would love to have some sort of pre-written text that you paste into an input field to see if it can "break" the code. For example the one of the simplest is just using various things like `' OR 1='1`, So I'm hoping there is some sort of pre written text ment for input fields and text fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a quick google gave me this page: http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/topic/7794-sql-injection-strings/ which lists plenty of examples.

Another: http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/topic/344-sql-injection-basic/

Edit: But like Mr. Alien says if you escape your SQL properly you won't have any problems so no need to test them all.

Comment: I do escape them, but it is always better safe than sorry :) I really appreciate the links. I searched google, but I apparently used the wrong criteria because I found nothing like these links, thanks!

Comment: FYI I searched for "sql injection examples" (without quotes)

Answer (score 1):

There are some handy lists in the links at the bottom of

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-005%29 and
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blind_SQL_Injection

(In general, the wider reading at [OWASP's SQL Injection pages](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) have lots of pointers...)